# Unable to find Path variable data

Tags: java, api, swagger, documentation, openapi

I have implemented the api

```java
@GetMapping("/mqsql-data/{tableName}")
public List<String, Object> getTableData(@Parameter(name="sigma", schema=@Schema(type="string", defaultValue="sigma") @PathVariable String tableName) {
    return service.getData(tableName);
}
```

added dependency : `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.11`

It is generating swagger ui.

when I am calling my api from browser and postman, I am getting the data means code is working fine but If I am trying to hitting api from swagger ui, value to tableName is not passing and getting below syntax error

`Incorrect syntax near '}'. I debug the code It is not taking tableName from swagger ui page.`

Can anybody help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's done, If anybody facing the same issue, Please define schema = @Schema() than only you can able to hit API with data in open api 1.6.x . I am not concluding that this is the only way but you can like this.

Comment: Change `@Parameter(name="sigma"` to `@Parameter(name="tableName"`. Does this help?